# Stop Jquery function to be execute twice

Tags: jquery

I have a image script like the way facebook display images. and i'm tring to add load more comments future to it, but i don't know how to do it. the function that load more comments execute twice. i made this simple code that describe my problem. [my simple code](https://jsfiddle.net/xusfj5bn/5/) . is there a way to stop the function from executing.

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.u_img' ,function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var img_id = $(this).attr('data-imgid');
    $('#overlay').css('display','block'); 
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url+"home/get_info_and_comments",
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        data: "img_id="+img_id,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#overlay_info").html(data);
            load_more(image_id);
            $("#cntrlnxpr a").on('click', function (d) {
                 d.preventDefault();
                 var img_id2 = $(this).data("imgid");
                 $.ajax({
                    url: base_url+"home/get_comments",
                    async: false,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: "img_id="+img_id2,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data2) {          
                        $("#sldhlper").load(base_url+"home/get_more_comments/"+data2['id']);
                        load_more(data2['id']);
                    }
                });
            });
        }        
    });
});

function scroll_func (my_var) {
    $('.container').scroll(function() {
        var erthis = $(this);
        var height = erthis.height();
        var all = erthis[0].scrollHeight;
        var top = erthis.scrollTop();
        if (top == all - height) 
        {
            // load more data
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why are you bind event handler inside a function?

Comment: @Satpal instead of writing the code twice i put it in a function

Comment: Sorry but I don't get your question

Comment: @phenxd see the jsfiddle in the link i provide above. and see the console log . so after you scroll to the bottom a function will execute thats normal . and when you click load more data and you scroll to the bottom you will notice that the function execute twice in the console log but i want a way to ignore the first event handler because i get new data throught ajax

Answer (score 0):

You should try and split your code into function, it would be easier to follow.

To answer your question, you have 2 options:

1- use a boolean variable to determine wether the function should execute or not.

```
var eventOneExecute = true;
var eventTwoExecute = false;

And then, in the first event, you swap those values.
// $(...).on('click', function() {
    if (eventOneExecute) {
        eventOneExecute = false;
        eventTwoExecute = true;
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

## 2- Which is the best practice, once you don't want an event to execute anymore, you unbind it.

[unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

```
$( "....").unbind( "click" );
```

Hope this helped!